# JavaScript/NodeJS: internal function don't executes immideately

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand, why in the below code `glob()` internal function don't executes immideately.

```
'use strict';

const glob = require('glob');

function testFunction(){

    console.log('Checkpoint 1');

    let objectWillBeFilled = {};

    glob(/* GlobPattern */, (errors, files) => {

        console.log('Checkpoint 2');

        files.forEach( (value, index, array) => {

            // do something ...
            // adding some key-value pairs to objectWillBeFilled ...

            console.log('Checkpoint 3');

        });
    });

    console.log('Checkpoint 4');

    return objectWillBeFilled;
}

testFunction();
```

I get the next sequence of the logs to console:

1. Checkpoint 1
2. Checkpoint 4
3. Checkpoint 2
4. Checkpoint 3

So, the `testFunction` returns the empty `objectWillBeFilled`. 
What I missed in JavaScript/Node JS learning?

Comment: The concept of asynchronicity, which is kind of the whole point of Node

Comment: return objectWillBeFilled once after the foreach loop is completely executed. You can use async module to use async.forEach and on complete return your result object.  Look: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html